# Select2 - create ajax with pre-loaded options

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have a fairly simple requirement set, but cannot for the life of me figure out how to achieve it with Select2...

1. I would like to have an input on the page
2. Which the user can type into to trigger an AJAX call
3. Which also displays a pre-loaded list of options that the user can click on instead of typing to trigger the AJAX.
4. If you close (blur) the input and then reopen it again then the previously loaded AJAX responses should still be displayed (instead of the options being blank and you having to start typing to load them again).

I can do #1 and #2 (or #1 and #3 of course!), but I cannot get all three requirements in one input field. I've not found any way to do #4.

Effectively, to achieve #3, I guess I'm looking for a way to inject my shortlist into what are normally the ajax-returned options and use something like #4 to make sure these are not cleared when the field is opened.

Is there a way to initialise the (normally Ajax loaded) options for a Select2 field? I've tried passing in `data` but it doesn't work, I tried using initSelection until I realised that wasn't relevant, I've tried all sorts of things, but to no avail...

Hopefully this is possible and I've just missed an option somewhere!

P.S. I've read several threads on Stack with similar titles to this but none of them seem to answer this question. If I've missed the vital one just let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this if you use Select2's `query` option, rather than the `ajax` option. That way you can make the ajax request if any characters have been typed, but show the default list if no characters have been typed.

If your default options are defined like this:

```
var DEFAULT_OPTIONS = [
    { id: 'def1', text: 'Default Choice 1' },
    { id: 'def2', text: 'Default Choice 2' },
    { id: 'def3', text: 'Default Choice 3' }
];
```

You could do the following:

```
var lastOptions = DEFAULT_OPTIONS;

$('#select').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 0,
    query: function(options) {
        if (options.term) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post', // Or 'get' if appropriate
                url: 'your_ajax_url',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    term: options.term // Change name to what is expected
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    lastOptions = data;
                    options.callback({ results: data });
                }
           });
        } else {
            options.callback({ results: lastOptions });
        }
    }
});
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7d9kdve/3/)**

Comment: You are a genius :) This looks very promising. I just need to figure out how to turn a fairly complex and paginated select2.ajax call into a $.ajax call!

Comment: @caponica - I've never used Select2's paging functionality before. I thought I'd try to expand on my answer above to support paging, and this is what I came up with: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9offcfun/)

Comment: you certainly know your select2! I have already gotten this working and it's responsive enough without pagination for now. When it comes time to paginate this (or any other select2 field) I'll go through your fiddle in more detail. Thank you so much for the follow up!

Comment: Note! This answer that uses the "query" option will not work with select2 version 4.x (you'll get a "`No select2/compat/query`" error) unless you include the "full" file instead of the normal version, because it includes a backwards compatibility feature. Reference: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/5472#issuecomment-488260793